# Element position changing from relative to fixed while scrolling in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, position, fixed

I have a problem i can't solve by myself and which I coudn't find a solution for.
I wrote a script in jQuery which works with Chrome and Firefox, but it doesn't work with IE (even the newest one).

At a glance HTML looks like this::

```
<div id="ContentThatIsAbove"></div>
<div id="someContainer">
      <div id="bonmenu_info_container" style="float: left;">
           <div id="bonmenu_info"></div> 
           <div id="1_info"></div> 
           <div id="2_info"></div> 
           <div id="3_info"></div> 
      </div>
      <div id="bonmenu" style="float: right;">
           <div class="1"></div>
           <div class="2"></div>
           <div class="3"></div>
      </div>

</div>
```

a jQuery script like this: ('$j' is used instead of '$')

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(window).load(function() {
    var MenuOffsetY = $j("#bonmenu").offset().top;
    $j(window).scroll(function(){
        if($j("html").position().top < -MenuOffsetY && $j("html").position().top >-1400 )
        {
            $j("#bonmenu_info_container").css('position', 'fixed');
            $j("#bonmenu_info_container").css('top', '0');  
            $j("#bonmenu_info_container").css('margin-top', '10px');
            $j("#bonmenu_info_container").fadeIn();
        }
        else if($j("html").position().top >= -MenuOffsetY)
        {
            $j("#bonmenu_info_container").css('position', 'relative');
            $j("#bonmenu_info_container").css('top', '');
            $j("#bonmenu_info_container").fadeIn(); 
        }
        else
        {
            $j("#bonmenu_info_container").fadeOut();
        }
    });
    $j("#bonmenu_info_container").children().hide();
    $j("#bonmenu_info").show();

    //This part below works perfectly everywhere.    
    $j("#bonmenu").mouseover(function(){
        $j(this).children().each(function(){
            var infoId = "#"+jQuery(this).attr('class')+"_info";
            $j(this).mouseover(function(){
                $j("#bonmenu_info_container").children().hide();
                $j(infoId).show();              
            });
        }); 
    }).mouseleave(function(){   
        $j("#bonmenu_info_container").children().hide();
        $j("#bonmenu_info").show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Explanation how it should work:

I don't want #bonmenu_info_container disappear in the top of a the window while scrolling the page. That's why in 1st if statemant I check if #bonmenu disappear in the top by checking html's position.top value. When the statement is true, css position value of #bonmenu_info_container should change from relative to fixed and vice versa.

You can see how it works on Chrome/FF: [http://bonappetea.com/menu](http://bonappetea.com/menu/)

What i nocited in Chrome/FF $('html').position().top's value changes while scrolling and in IE it doesn't. Do you know why? Or do you have better solution than mine?

I have totally no idea what to do with this code and i don't want to start it all from zero.

Comment: Why all the hassle of changing the divs position from relative to absolute with this script? You can just setup the div as a fixed directly without DOM manipulation. Just line out the space behind the fixed div in the top, then you'll have the same effect.

Comment: @Martin
Let's say your window's height is 600px, div is the same height and you need the space behind the div to be 400px from the top in the initial form. In result, after you scroll down you'll only see 200px of the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it doesn't. But `body`'s position changes, so you need to check what changed and take an action accordingly.

```
var preScrollHtml = document.getElementsByTagName('html').item(0).scrollTop,
    preScrollBody = document.getElementsByTagName('body').item(0).scrollTop;

$j(window).scroll(function(){
   var scrolledHtml = document.getElementsByTagName('html').item(0).scrollTop,
       scrolledBody = document.getElementsByTagName('body').item(0).scrollTop;

   var scrolledVal = scrolledHtml != preScrollHtml ? scrolledHtml : scrolledBody;

   if(scrolledVal < -MenuOffsetY && scrolledVal >-1400 ) {}

   // here all your logic is

   // just before end of the handler reset values of these
   preScrollHtml = scrolledHtml;
   preScrollBody = scrolledBody;
}
```

and so on

Comment: Thank you so much,  i tried .scrollTop() before, but don't know why it did not work. Now it does. I really appreciate your help!